# SQL Syntax to count number of digits in the whole number portion of a Decimal value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am looking for SQL Syntax to count number of digits in the whole number portion of a decimal value.

Example : `E001.0`

For this, I expect 4

and `E00.10`

For this, I expect 3.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b19c7/2

My table has more than 100,000 records. I need to get only distinct count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `substring` and `charindex`.

```
SELECT distinct 
case when charindex('.',value) > 0 then len(substring(value, 1, charindex('.',value)-1))
else len(value) end as lngth
from Numbers
```

Comment: my sqlfiddle is throwing exception error on running the query .. can you please try it in my sqlfiddle post

Comment: i am sure it will run. i have some issues with fiddle. you can try it in your database and check.

Comment: Getting error as ..
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: did you try the most latest version?

Comment: some strings don't have a decimal, add a `CASE` expression so you don't try to pass `-1` to `SUBSTRING()`

Comment: @HartCO..realized it and modified it a while ago

Comment: @vkp ah, didn't see update, odd that he said that error came after your update, must not have tried the new version.